# Why can't I connect to my pgsql database from another language?

Tags: python, c#, postgresql, windows

Sorry if the question is stupid but I'm learning SQL and I've searched for days without a solution. Basically using PostgresSQL from CMD works perfectly, I can create the database, can connect, create tables, insert modify, etc. The problem arises when recently I've tried to manipulate my database from another language (tried with c# and python) but when I try the connection I get the error:
`database 'Biblioteca' does not exist`.

I know that's not the case because of course it's in my computer, but also if i change the correct password to an incorrect one in my connection line such as this:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server = localhost; " +
            "User Id= admin; Password = wrongpass; Database =Biblioteca");
```

I instead get the error:

> password authentication failed for user "admin"

Which tells me that the program can indeed tell the database exists, it just choses to ignore for some reason, am I doing something wrog? Need every help i can get

Note: I'm working on Windows.

Comment: Do not get Authentication and Credentials confused.  You have a frontend and a backend.  Authentication is used on frontend to make connection.  Then credentials are used in the backend to connect to database.  The database library is the driver than is used in the connection string for the database.  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

Comment: `database 'Library' does not exist`, but in your connection string, you use database 'Biblioteca', so I would expect an error like `database 'Biblioteca' does not exist`. Do you by chance have tried to connect to 2 different databases?

Comment: Try providing a port as well, as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844014/6133426). Check your PG config file to see which port to use (should be 5432). Also, have you configured the DSN to be able to use your application to connect to the database? Your CMD communication with the PG DB is probably done with psql, and that's why it's succeeding.

Comment: 1) No this *password authentication failed for user "admin"* is just telling you that you are using the wrong password. Roles(users) are global to the database cluster and their presence and password are checked before the database is connected to. 2) Are you sure this `Biblioteca` is the correct case of the database name. Using `psql` what does `\l` show for the name?